# Capybara's have_selector doesn't see jQuery fileupload input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec2, jquery-file-upload

I'm using Rails 3.2.14, Capybara 2.1.0, jquery-fileupload-rails 0.4.1.

If I try to write tests around file upload, but the file input is not found by capybara. The spec fragment:

```
  describe "Create with all required fields filled" do
    before do
      choose "Revision File"
      select "Publish", from: "file_asset[file_type_ref_id]"
      click_button "Next"
      script = "$('input[type=file]').show();" # added later
      page.driver.browser.execute_script(script)
      print page.html # to debug the page
      subject { page }
    end

    describe "Save should create a FileAsset" do
      it { should have_selector("span.fileinput-button span") }
      it { should have_selector("span.fileinput-button input") }
    end
```

The rspec result:

```
Failures:

  1) FileAsset Pages New-Create (revision file) Without Authorizations Create with all required fields filled Save should create a FileAsset
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector("span.fileinput-button input") }
       expected #has_selector?("span.fileinput-button input") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/file_asset_pages_spec.rb:63:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 16.95 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure
```

I.e., the first example runs successfully, but the second not, however the html page contains both (output fragment of `print page.html`):

```
<div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
  <div class="span7">
    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-small btn-success fileinput-button">
      <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
      <span>Select and Upload File</span>
      <input type="file" name="upload[upload]" id="upload_upload" />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The input is not hidden, the span is found in the same div. I've tried of course "#upload_upload" as selector, the result is the same. In the spec I added the two lines to `show()` the input later, the result is the same without them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue is [solved](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1163) so far, that the file input field is found by the command `it { should have_selector("span.fileinput-button input", visible: false) }`. However the original problem is not solved: I'am not able to test the fileupload itself. The following command does nothing, as I see in selenium's firefox instance: `page.find("#upload_upload", visible:false).set('/tmp/test.txt')`